# PHP preg_replace with consecutive number of times depending on the match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have strings like below in a php string, which i want to replace with tabs characters depending on the value after the [(number of times tab will appear)) ...]

```
[4m ljjklj klj lkj lkjlj lk[]
[3m ljjklj klj lkj lkjlj lk[]
[m ljjklj klj lkj lkjlj ljk l
```

i have written the following code

```
$string_log=  preg_replace('/\[(.*?)m/',"\t",$string_log);
```

which replaces with one tab character, however i need to replace it with depending on the number in-front of the letter m .

for example  if the string is

```
[4m] then it should be \t\t\t\t
[m] then it should be \t
[2m] then it should be \t\t
```

how can achieve this in php with preg_replace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string_log = preg_replace_callback('/\[(.*?)m/', function ($match) {
    if ($match[1]) $count = $match[1];
    else $count = 1;
    return str_repeat("\t", $count);
}, $string_log);
```

If you have to use plain `preg_replace` and can't use another function, then I think you will have to use the `/e` modifier to execute code for each match, which is very dangerous and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a callback to achieve this.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\[(\d*)m~', 
     function($m) {
         $count = $m[1] ?: 1;
         return str_repeat("\t", $count);
      }, $str);
```

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/206951)

Comment: I discover a funny trick today, since php 5.3 you can write `$count = $m[1] ?: 1;`